# The probability that a student will receive a point if he correctly selects both specific elements from a set of 20 elements.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

At chemistry classes, the student receives a set of 20 names of chemical compounds. Among them there are two lipids that should be underlined. If both correct lipids are marked correctly, the student gets a point. Rightfully? Is such success trustworthy? How likely is it to get a point in this way of checking knowledge in the complete ignorance of the student? How likely is it to hit one lipid?
My answers to the last two questions:

- Both lipids: $\frac{\binom{2}{2}}{\binom{20}{2}} = \frac{1}{190} = 0.00526... ≈ 0.53$%
- Exactly one lipid: $\frac{\binom{2}{1}*\binom{18}{1}}{\binom{20}{2}} = \frac{18}{95} = 0.18947... ≈ 18.95$%

But what should be the answers to the first two questions? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculations are correct.  The probability of missing both answers is $$\frac{\binom{18}{2}}{\binom{20}{2}} = \frac{153}{190},$$ and since the number of correct guesses can only be $0$, $1$, or $2$, we see that these probabilities must add to $1$:
$$\frac{1}{190} + \frac{18}{95} + \frac{153}{190} = \frac{1 + 36 + 153}{190} = 1.$$

As to the question of whether such a success is "trustworthy," that depends on the tolerance for error.  If the instructor wants no more than $1\%$ of students who guess randomly to get both choices correct (and therefore receive a point), then this method is sufficiently trustworthy, because the probability is $0.526316\% < 1\%$.  But if the instructor wants no more than $0.1\%$ of such students to receive a point by guessing, then it is insufficient.  The question could be redesigned; e.g., identify $3$ out of $3$ correct choices among $20$ possibilities, which has a probability of $$\frac{1}{\binom{20}{3}} = \frac{1}{1140} \approx 0.0877193\% < 0.1\%.$$

Comment: Well, there is no specification from the instructor, but okay, thanks for the answer. But what about the question, if it is rightfully?